# How do I open a tag with <C-]> but open it in an existing split?

Tags: vim-windows

I usually always have only two vertical splits open. One I use for actual coding and the other for reference. I would like to be able to search for tag  in Window1 and have the result appear in Window2. Is this possible?

Comment: Assuming you only want your "tag-split" to appear on the right split always and when there is only two vertical splits, it's not that hard. I could think of some keymappings like, `nnoremap <c-]> <c-w>o<c-w>v<c-w>l<c-]>` But that's lazy. If you find yourself doing that often enough, then you should consider building a function for it.

Comment: `set switchbuf=useopen` then use `<c-w><c-]>`

Comment: @EnanAjmain Thanks that does work. It does seem messy and does assume that the specific position of the window. But should work in my case.

Comment: @Mass I tried that and wasn't able to get it to work. It always does a split instead of a vsplit. Although, I do actually like that functionality and will probably use it in the future. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: yes, unfortunately there is no way to have it always open vertically, but you can use a mapping: `nnoremap <silent> <c-w>] :vert winc ]<cr>`

Comment: I actually just posted a question regarding this. For some reason, I can't seem to remap chords. So when I add your mapping to my vimrc, <c-w>] still does the default action instead of what it was remapped to. Does this work for you?

Comment: oh, you wanted to know about **that** keychord! And the mapping provided by @Mass should work, it works for me. You should **debug your vimrc**. Just yesterday I stumbled upon a similar problem. [You can check here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16392/how-do-i-change-not-add-to-keymaps-of-default-vim) if you have something in common.