# What is the difference between unmap and mapping to <Nop>?

Tags: key-bindings

My version is : NVIM v0.3.0-dev

I'm trying to replace  mappings with w mappings. Initially I came up with

```
nnoremap <leader>w <c-w>
nnoremap <leader>wb <c-w>s
nnoremap <leader>ws <nop>
unmap <c-w>
```

But it didn't work. I didn't have any  mappings with w. After a minute I came up with this:

```
nnoremap <leader>w <c-w>
nnoremap <leader>wb <c-w>s
nnoremap <leader>ws <nop>
nnoremap <c-w> <nop>
```

This works as I expect it to. I was just wondering why my previous attempt didn't bear fruit. What's the difference between unmap and nnoremap to `<nop>` ?  And what is the convention to this sort of things.

**N.B**: I want to unmap cause I'm used to those default keymaps, but I'm having pinky issues with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> lately. So, I want to train myself to use  mappings instead.

Comment: If you dont want to obliterate all the window control keys (some of them are quite useful) the trick I used was `nnoremap <Leader>w <C-w>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is important to first understand that `<c-w>` is not a map but a built-in command when vim is operating in a particular mode.  It is often referred to as a "normal command" since one uses it in normal mode<sup>1</sup>, and it can be  triggered using the `:normal!` command.  There is no mapping involved; the normal commands are hard coded in C.  If you open up [normal.c](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/c8523e2e6cd072d86a9412f465aa9eef53f5675e/src/normal.c#L244), you can see the character `^W` is to associated with the function `nv_window` in a large, fixed, data table of normal commands.

Although mappings allow you to override default behavior, you cannot change the built-ins and they can always be accessed using `noremap`, `:normal!`, `feedkeys(..,'n')`, etc.  When vim is processing input when mappings are allowed, such as in `map`, `:normal`, `feedkeys(..,'m')`, it first checks if there are any mappings which match, then continues processing normal commands or until an invalid sequence is encountered.

This explains why you cannot `unmap` a built-in normal command and why you *can* `nnoremap` to a `<nop>`, which is specifically designed for this purpose.  Why would you choose `nnoremap` instead of `nmap` in this case?  Well, there's not a great reason, but the convention is to use `*noremap` always, unless you *really* need remapping.  A good example of when to use an `nmap` is those to `<plug>` mappings in a plugin.

Side note: you might wonder why there are the `:map` and `:map!` forms in addition to `nmap`, `vmap`, etc.  Originally, in vi there were two main modes; (normal) command and insert, so having two forms made sense.  However, to write robust code, it is almost always better to spell it out in each mode.

<sub>1. At one time normal mode was referred to as command mode and visual mode, but forget about this entirely.</sub>

Comment: Good answer. But you didn't specifically say if my 2nd process (one which worked) was correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

`umap XXX` may get error if there is no such mapping.

`map XXX <Nop>` won't get error in that case and can disable vim's original(built in) command, such as d or s or  c, while umap can't.

Example

from a plugin named 'vim-sandwich'

```
NOTE: To prevent unintended operation, the following setting is strongly
      recommended to add to your vimrc.
>
    nmap s <Nop>
    xmap s <Nop>
<
      |s| could be easily replaced by |c|l| commands.
```

```
KEYMAPPINGS             *sandwich-keymappings*

This plugin defines the following keymappings.

function    default keymappings
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
add     sa{motion/textobject}{addition} (normal and visual mode)
......
```

if we use `silent! umap s` instead, when we want to use `sa`, we may actually call the `s` command because of time out.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? `:silent! unmap XXX` is better if you want to silence errors. You also didn't address the difference between the two for builtin commands like C-w

Comment: Thank you. Updated