# Open ctrl+] in a new split?

Tags: split, jump

How can I open the result of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> in a new split?

<sup>similar: [How do I open a tag with ctrl+] but open it in an existing split?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16385/5224)</sup>

Comment: I can’t find any reference to it, but does `<C-w><C-]>` work?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, it does! (albeit a horizontal split)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do it:

```
CTRL-W ]                    *CTRL-W_]* *CTRL-W_CTRL-]*
CTRL-W CTRL-]   Split current window in two.  Use identifier under cursor as a
        tag and jump to it in the new upper window.
        In Visual mode uses the Visually selected text as a tag.
        Make new window N high.
```

<sub>courtesy: [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18185/open-ctrl-in-a-new-split/18192#comment31327_18185)</sub>

Comment: One could even remap the commands to use a vertical split

Comment: how? @D.BenKnoble

Comment: @AyushMandowara _e.g._, `nnoremap <C-w>] :vertical stag <cword><CR>`. `<C-w>]` and variants are just aliases for `:stag <cword><CR>` if you read the description.

Comment: It's not strictly true that they're aliases. If you use these Ex-command formulation, a different "flags" argument gets passed to `:help tag-function`. With regular `<C-w>]` the flag `'c'` is passed, while your formulation passes an empty flag.